# How add a anchor link in document library site column?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view, calculated-column, hyperlink

I want to add an anchor link in a document library to redirect to another page. How can I do this? The anchor link is:

`<a onclick="javascript:location.href='UploadDocuments.aspx' + location.search">Save</a>`

Comment: You want it in Dispform or in Allitems?

Comment: I want to add this anchor link in Allitems.aspx Page. how can I do this please help me. thanks

Comment: When I am using this link in calculate column syntax error has occurs . what syntax need to add this- <a onclick="javascript:location.href='UploadDocuments.aspx' + location.search">Save</a>   link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When used in a Calculated Column Formula (set tot datatype=Number/DateTime so it outputs as HTML in A View (and View only)) you have to escape the "(double quote) properly:

```
="<a onclick=""javascript:location.href='UploadDocuments.aspx' + location.search"">Save</a>"
```

Comment: Link is working fine and redirect to another page using above formula but SPHostUrl is not passed to redirect page using "location.search". What may be reason for that ?

Comment: I copied your code; Does it require a **?** to specify ``location.search`` as parameter maybe...

Comment: I have try ? in to specify location.search as parameter but it redirect to target page but SPHost Url is not passes still. please give me another solution for this.

Comment: Forget all the SharePoint stuff; first get your URL right

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Client Side Rendering and JSLinks. Sample code can be found [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)

Answer (score 0):

You can use approach of using calculated column and achieve your functionality..

Look into this blog, this will provide you all you need to create hyperlink using Caluclated Column on List View.

https://devdotnotes.wordpress.com/2012/01/29/sharepoint-caculated-column-and-hyperlink-no-workflow-or-script-needed/